# Derivative of surface normal vector with respect to curve parameter

Tags: differential-geometry

Let the surface is given by $r(u,v)$, and we have a curve $r(u(s),v(s))$ with unit speed on this surface, is there simple relation for the derivative of surface normal with respect to the parameter $s$?